# Solr tokenizer base on dictionary

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to tokenize a field on Solr using both **WhitespaceTokenizer** and a custom user dictionary. So for example:

Input: New York is the most populous city in the United States.

Analyzer result:  "New York", "populous", "city", "United States"

Given the custom dictionary contains "New York" and "United States" so these terms will not be parse into tokens as other.

I have searched through provided tokenizer library, but still not found a perfect fit.

Comment: Have you tried the stopword filter(solr.StopFilterFactory)?

Comment: Hi Leoh, thank you for your reply. I think StopFilter is used to filter out words. On the other hand, I want to keep some term untouch through the Analyzer step. For example: "New York" -> "New York" instead of "New", "York"

Comment: I do have same kind of requirement but still can't find anything. Please post if something worked for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, while I don't know your requirements, it seems very likely that simply using a [phrase query](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html) (like `content:"New York"`) would serve your purpose here.  In that case, appropriate query construction is definitely the easier solution.

---

Barring that, you could make use of a [`CommonGramsFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/commongrams/CommonGramsFilter.html) in your analysis chain.

`CommonGramsFilter` will split out common grams as separate tokens, with position increments set appropriately to allow correct phrase searching, allowing you to search either by the individual tokens or the grams, depending on what is present in the query.  You need to pass in a `Set` or terms to be handled in this way.  See the [example in the Analyzer documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html?is-external=true) for how to define your analyzer with a custom set of filters.

To incorporate it into `StandardAnalyzer`, I would probably place it just before the `StopAnalyzer` (that is:  `StandardTokenizer` --> `StandardFilter` --> `LowercaseFilter` --> `CommonGramsFilter` --> `StopFilter`).

Keep in mind that, when using this filter, you must use a different analyzer to parse queries.  Make sure to use `CommonGramsFilter` when indexing, and `CommonGramsQueryFilter` when querying with a queryparser.

So, in the end, you might have something like:

```
Analyzer indexAnalyzer = new Analyzer() {
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        final StandardTokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_48, reader);
        TokenStream filter = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_48, tokenizer);
        filter = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_48, filter);
        filter = new CommonGramsFilter(Version.LUCENE_48, filter, myCommonGrams);
        filter = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_48, filter, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, filter);
    }
};

Analyzer queryAnalyzer = new Analyzer() {
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        final StandardTokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_48, reader);
        TokenStream filter = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_48, tokenizer);
        filter = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_48, filter);
        filter = new CommonGramsFilter(Version.LUCENE_48, filter, myCommonGrams);
        filter = new CommonGramsQueryFilter(filter);
        filter = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_48, filter, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, filter);
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi femtoRgon, thank you for your thorough reply. I checking if it work. Will inform the result soon.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible options is to use the WordDelimiterFilterFactory to do the actual tokenisation and provide a text file with a list of protected words and pass it through the protected parameter.

The list of words that appear in the protected words list will not be split into sub-tokens.

To get this to work properly, you might need to use the KeywordTokenizerFactory as the tokeniser.

Example:

```
  <fieldType name="prottext" class="solr.TextField" indexed="true" stored="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
              <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
              <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="0" protected="protwords.txt"/>
              <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

For more details see: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory

And look at the usage of the protected parameter.

Comment: I believe WordDelimiterFilter's protWords only match against whole terms.  Works reasonably predictably with the likes of `StandardTokenizer` or `WhitespaceTokenizer` tokenizing the input before hitting that check, but not very useful with `KeywordTokenizer`, where the content hasn't been tokenized beforehand.